# reducer return state twice, how to update in store?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reducers

My reducer returns state in a async way, since it will interact with another component, how to make the component re-render after reducer update state in the .then?

switch (action.type) {

```
case RELEASE_PAYMENT:

(new PaypalContract())
            .releasePayment(action.id)
            .then(() => (new PaypalContract()).getState(action.id))
            .then(function(e) {
                console.log("status in orderReducer:",status[e])
                return{
                  ...state,
                  orderStatus: status[e]
                }
            })
return state
```

Comment: To interact with async function, such as fetch data or a underlying smart contract,  I think it is neat to put functions either in reducer or action,  not in react component.  Since a successful async function will firstly feedback a 'pending' then after it gets the required data, it will return 'fulfilled'. So 'redux-promise-middleware' might be what I actually need in this situation.  I need to change something in the action and reducer to make it work: https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware/blob/main/docs/guides/reducers.md

Answer (score 2):

You can't return the state twice from the reducer function and you can't return the updated state from the reducer function in an asynchronous way.

Returning something from the callback function of the `.then()` method doesn't makes it a return value of the outer function, i.e. reducer function in your case.

Reducer functions are synchronous, they take in a action and based on the action return the updated state. All of this is done synchronously.

What you are doing in your reducer function won't work as you expect it to and the `return` statement at the of your reducer function will always execute before asynchronous code completes. This means that your reducer function always returns the same state which means that your redux store never updates.

#### Solution

What you need is a way to dispatch an action that triggers the data fetching and once the data is available, another action should be dispatched that is received by the reducer function. This new action should contain the data that is fetched asynchronously, as a payload and the reducer function will just update the state appropriately using the payload associated with the action.

Following are the couple of options that allow you to do just that:

- [`redux thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)
- [`Redux Saga`](https://redux-saga.js.org/)

Using the first option is easier so i would recommend to start with that but you could also explore the second option which also help with advanced use cases.

Here are couple of resources to get you started with each of the options mentioned above:

- [`Redux Thunk Explained with Examples`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/redux-thunk-explained-with-examples/#:%7E:text=Redux%20Thunk%20is%20middleware%20that,to%20send%20a%20GET%20request.)
- [`Redux Saga Example`](https://medium.com/@lavitr01051977/make-your-first-call-to-api-using-redux-saga-15aa995df5b6#:%7E:text=Click%20Here%20to%20see%20a%20live%20example%20of%20what%20we,redux%20app%20nice%20and%20simple.&text=Contrary%20to%20redux%20thunk%2C%20you,and%20your%20actions%20stay%20pure.)

Comment: It looks redux thunk and redux saga are used to react components  to play with async fetch. For a react/redux to interact with smart contract in blockchain, I think it might be neater to put those interaction on either action or reducer, not in the UI components.   Reducer is sync so it might be better to have action module to send more message to reducer, such as 'pending', 'fulfilled', I searched on line then found redux-promise-middleware might what I am exactly after.  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: `redux-promise-middleware` will also work but `redux-thunk` and `redux-saga` also do what you want. React component just dispatches an action to start the data fetching process and actual data fetching happens outside of the component. You can use either one of them to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data to the reducer after you get the response from the API. It will be simpler to control the flow of data. You can make use of `async/await` in this.

```
async function_name() {
   const res = await API_CALL_HERE
   res.then( data => INVOKE_YOUR_DISPATCH_HERE(data))
      .catch(err => console.log('error'));
}
```

In reducer

```
 case RELEASE_PAYMENT:
  return {...state, orderStauts:data[e]
```